# Passing Array of Dates From Controller to JavaScript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, date, datepicker

I have a DatePicker in one of my Laravel views. I'm trying to pass an array of dates to the DatePicker from the controller to make these dates inactive on the page (the user should not be able to make a booking on those dates).

**Controller/JavaScript**

```php
<?php

function show(Tour $tour) {
    $tourdates = DB::table('tourdates')
        ->join('tours', 'tourdates.tour_id', '=', 'tours.id')
        ->select('tourdates.tour_date')
        ->get();

    return view('tours.show', compact('tourdates'));
}
?>

<script>
    var disableddates = {!! json_encode($tourdates->toArray()) !!};

    function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
        return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }

    var dateToday = new Date();
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateformat: "mm/dd/yy",
            minDate: dateToday,
            maxDate: "1Y + 1M + 1D",
            beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
        });
    });
</script>
```

The dates I pass do not become inactive. I think it's because the date format of the array is yyyy-mm-dd and the format in DatePicker is mm/dd/yy. However, I don't seem to be able to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Give the format that your datepicker understands, to resolve this try formatting your array before sending to the datepicker.

Comment: Why would you `json_encode()` it? What's the evil `'` after `json_encode($tourdates->toArray())`?

Comment: Hi, I'm using it to pass php array to javascript. I removed ', It wasn't in my original code, so i don't know how it got here :))

Comment: Yes, that worked! I formatted the date array in the controller and passed it to the DatePicker. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format passed to `formatDate()` to match the format used in the array

Change:

```
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
```

To

```
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
```

Comment: Show us the actual source version you see in browser rather than the php code. Makes it easier to run this in a demo to test

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix the issue is that I formatted the date in the controller rather than in blade and modified my javascript accordingly. Below is the adjusted code:

```
<?php

function show(Tour $tour) {
    $tourdates = DB::table('tourdates')
        ->join('tours', 'tourdates.tour_id', '=', 'tours.id')
        ->select('tourdates.tour_date')
        ->get();

    foreach ($tourdates as $td) {
            $tourdates1[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($td->tour_date));

    return view('tours.show', compact('tourdates'));
}
?>

<script>
    var disableddates = {!! json_encode($tourdates1) !!};

    function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
        return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }

    var dateToday = new Date();
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateformat: "mm/dd/yy",
            minDate: dateToday,
            maxDate: "1Y + 1M + 1D",
            beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
        });
    });
</script>
```